# Replacing multiple words in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know if there a more effective way to replace multiple words with a single word, than this:

```
variableName.replace(/\small/g , 'word').replace(/\medium/g , 'word').replace(/\large/g , 'word').replace(/\x_large/g , 'word');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - modify your pattern to accept multiple options.

```
variableName.replace(/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b/g, 'word');
```

Also important to use word boundaries (`\b`) to ensure you match the words by themselves, not as part of other words (e.g. bridge vs. abridged)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [**alternation**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`

```js
let str = 'w1 hello w2 how are you w3'

let op = str.replace(/\bw1|w2|w3\b/g, '')

console.log(op)
```